# Arabic letter in iText 7

Tags: java, itext7, html2pdf

I have tried to set Arabic font but the RTL is not working even though I set the direction from Right To Left in my HTML file.
I have used FontProvider but still Arabic isn't working properly.

// this is the result I got

[image]

//that is the code I have used

```
public static final String[] FONTS = { "src/main/resources/fonts/noto/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf",
        "src/main/resources/fonts/noto/arial.ttf" };


String htmlString = null;
        try {
            htmlString = FileUtils.readFileToString(htmlTemplateFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
        
        FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
        for (String font : FONTS) {
            FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(font);
            fontProvider.addFont(fontProgram);
        }
        properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
        properties.setCharset("UTF-8");

        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlString, baos, properties);
```

// that is a part of my html file

```
<table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td dir="rtl" style="font-family: Noto Naskh Arabic">قرأت
                                        جميع بنود المدونة خلف هذا العقد المكتوبة بالفرنسية و قبلت بها
                                        و أتحمل مسؤولية السيارة خلال مدة هذا العقد</td>

                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>J'ai lu et j'accepte les formes mentionnées au recto
                                        et verso de présent contrat et du carnet de bord</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td dir="rtl" style="font-family: Noto Naskh Arabic">
                                        شركة %currentUserName% لها كامل الصلاحية في إسترجاع سيارتها في أي
                                        وقت وذلك وبدون أي تعويض</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>La Sté %currentUserName% se réserve le plein droit de
                                        récupérer la voiture à tous moment sans justif ni indermnité</td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: `HtmlConverter` is a class from iText 7 so I edited your question (you mentioned iText 5 initially).

Comment: Have you installed [pdfCalligraph](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfcalligraph)?